# get only zipcode from the address in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

select Address from ODLN

This is my results:

> ```
> 15 Changi North Way Level 2 SSG WH Singapore 498770 (8:30am ~ 5pm; Avoid 11:30am ~ 1:30pm, send before 4pm)
> 15 Changi North Way Level 2 SSG WH Singapore 498770 (8:30am ~ 5pm; Avoid 11:30am ~ 1:30pm, send before 4pm)
> 15 Changi North Way Level 2 SSG WH Singapore 498770 (8:30am ~ 5pm; Avoid 11:30am ~ 1:30pm, send before 4pm)
> 200 Victoria Street #03-09  Bugis Junction  Singapore 188021 Singapore
> 348 Jalan Boon Lay (Lunch: 12pm ~ 1pm) Singapore 619529
> 46 Penjuru Lane, Level 4 (Office), C&P Hub 3 Singapore 609206 (Avoid Lunch Time: 11.30am to 1pm, deliver before 4pm)
> 46 Penjuru Lane, Level 4 (Office), C&P Hub 3 Singapore 609206 (Avoid Lunch Time: 11.30am to 1pm, deliver before 4pm)
> ```

I need my results:

```
498770 
498770
498770  
188021
619529
609206
609206
```

Comment: Is your address always in Singapore?  Is the zip code always 6 digits?  If these are not true, how do you suggest identifying the zip code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, its always Singapore with 6 digits

Comment: . .In that case, you should accept Tim's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we make the assumption that the 6 digit ZIP code would always appear after the text `Singapore`, then we can use the base string functions here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(address, CHARINDEX('Singapore', address) + 10, 6) AS zip
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo